# Why does regular expression think chr(181) and chr(956) are the same when ignoring case?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-re

## 1. What I met

My following code:

```py
import re

txt = 'μ'

lst = [
    chr(181),
    chr(956)
]

for c in lst:
    print(c)
    reObj = re.compile(c, re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE )
    print(list(re.finditer(reObj, txt)))
```

displays:

```
µ
[<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='μ'>]
μ
[<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='μ'>]
```

which means `chr(181) == chr(956)` by using `IGNORECASE`.

I can understand the upper/lower case of non-English letters:

```py
>>> 'a'.upper()
'A'
```

## 2. My questions

### 2.1 how to get the upper/lower case of non-English letters

since I found:

```py
>>> chr(181).upper()
'Μ'
```

which I suppose that it should give me the character `chr(956)`, but;

```py
>>> chr(956).upper()
'Μ'
>>> chr(956).upper() == chr(181).upper()
True
>>> chr(181).lower()
'µ'
>>> chr(956).lower()
'μ'
>>> chr(181).lower() == chr(956).lower()
False
```

### 2.2 Is there a detailed documents on such `upper/lower case`, for example, a table.

Thanks

Comment: Use [`.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) instead of `.lower`.

Comment: The short answer is "Unicode normalization". There are many existing questions about this, though I can't recall seeing exactly this. A common type of question revolves around decomposed vs composed representations (for example, **ö** can be represented as a single legacy Latin-1 character, or as **o** followed by the combining diaeresis, and then the OP will be confused because some comparison operators regard the two as identical, whereas a simple string equality comparison reveals that they are different).

Comment: Character 181 is the micro sign. Character 956 is the small Greek letter mu. Both have the same uppercase counterpart, the capital Greek letter mu (924). In general you cannot assume that x.lower().upper() or x.upper().lower() is the same as x.

Comment: For an extra fun related problem, check out the turkish dotless i. It's so famous that it's got [its own Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I_in_computing).

Comment: the re module would appear to implement simple loose matches of basic (level 1) Unicode support rather than level 2 support which would require full case folding. So re module would not support special casings, only simple casings. So micro/mu is supported but situations when casing results in a change in string length
or is dependent on context or locale would not be supported.